# Parse shapefile (shp file) without shx and dbf files

Tags: c#, shapefile

I need to upload a shapefile and store all shapes in database. I spent two days to finding a good library but so far I do not find any complete solution.

I try to parse the file with 'Catfood.Shapefile' library, but it needs two other file beside of .shp file which I do not have.

I manage to implement a code in Java but now I need to re-implement it in c#.

please give me some advice!

Comment: Those files *are* needed. A shapefile isn't a standalone file. It's actually the combination of shape, index and metadata files. Without them, you only have a bunch of points with no meaningful metadata. Either find the missing shapefile files and add them to the same folder, or check whether you can force the library to work without them. Without the metadata though, how are you going to match the shapes to any other data and use them?

Comment: you know in Java I have these line 

 prefs = new ValidationPreferences();
   int avl = fis.available();
   prefs.setMaxNumberOfPointsPerShape(16650);
   shapeFileReader = new ShapeFileReader(fis, prefs);

and I do have those two files

Comment: Then what is the question? Why don't you use these files with your C# code as well?

Comment: these library available in java not in c# :)

Comment: The `shx` and `dbf` files aren't libraries. They are data files just like `shp`. In fact, the three files shouldn't be separated. Just put them in the same folder as the `shp` file. These files are *mandatory*. Without them, you don't have a shapefile

Comment: Java has a library which are simulates shx and dbf. by those library you can parse shp file. but those library are not available in c#.

Comment: In our problem, the customer is handing us a .shp file as a convenient collection of points. They don't have any metadata, and they don't want to bother sending us files for metadata that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Shp file is a well design file which you can see the description [here](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf). the shx and dbf only add some help to parse shp file. I add a class into [Catfood.Shapefile](https://shapefile.codeplex.com/) which its name is ShpParser. The input of this class is only Shp file. it does not need to shx and dbf file to extract the shapes in the file.

if the meta data is null, two classes are throw exception, make sure you remove metadata exceptions from following method:

1- Shape constructor
2- ShapeFactory.ParseShape

and here the code of ShpParser

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Data.OleDb;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Text;

 namespace Catfood.Shapefile
 { 
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public class ShpParser : IDisposable, IEnumerator<Shape>, IEnumerable<Shape>
{
    private bool _disposed;
    private bool _opened;
    private int _currentIndex;
    private int _count;
    private RectangleD _boundingBox;
    private ShapeType _type;
    private int _currentPosition;
    private FileStream _mainStream;
    private Header _mainHeader;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public ShpParser()
    {
        _currentIndex = -1;
        _currentPosition = 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path"></param>
    public ShpParser(string path)
        : this()
    {
        Open(path);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path"></param>
    private void Open(string path)
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("ShpParser");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
        }

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("shp file not found", path);
        }

        _mainStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

        if (_mainStream.Length < Header.HeaderLength)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Shapefile main file does not contain a valid header");
        }

        // read in and parse the headers
        var headerBytes = new byte[Header.HeaderLength];
        _mainStream.Read(headerBytes, 0, Header.HeaderLength);
        _mainHeader = new Header(headerBytes);
        _type = _mainHeader.ShapeType;
        _boundingBox = new RectangleD(_mainHeader.XMin, _mainHeader.YMin, _mainHeader.XMax, _mainHeader.YMax);

        _currentPosition = Header.HeaderLength;

        _count = _mainHeader.FileLength * 2; // FileLength return the size of file in words (16 bytes)
        _opened = true;

    }
    #region IDisposable Members
    /// <summary>
    /// Close the Shapefile. Equivalent to calling Dispose().
    /// </summary>
    public void Close()
    {
        Dispose();
    }



    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool canDisposeManagedResources)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (canDisposeManagedResources)
            {
                if (_mainStream != null)
                {
                    _mainStream.Close();
                    _mainStream = null;
                }
            }
            _disposed = true;
            _opened = false;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (_disposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException("ShpParser");
        if (!_opened) throw new InvalidOperationException("ShpParser not open.");

        if (_currentPosition < (_count - 1))
        {
            // try to read the next database record
           return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // reached the last shape
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        if (_disposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException("ShpParser");
        if (!_opened) throw new InvalidOperationException("ShpParser not open.");

        _currentIndex = -1;
    }

    public Shape Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (_disposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException("ShpParser");
            if (!_opened) throw new InvalidOperationException("ShpParser not open.");


            //get recordheader;
            var recordheader = new byte[8];


            _mainStream.Read(recordheader, 0, recordheader.Length);


            int contentOffsetInWords = EndianBitConverter.ToInt32(recordheader, 0, ProvidedOrder.Big);
            int contentLengthInWords = EndianBitConverter.ToInt32(recordheader, 4, ProvidedOrder.Big);


            _mainStream.Seek(_currentPosition , SeekOrigin.Begin); // back to header of record 
            int bytesToRead = (contentLengthInWords * 2) + 8;
            byte[] shapeData = new byte[bytesToRead];
            _currentPosition += bytesToRead;
            _mainStream.Read(shapeData, 0, bytesToRead);
            return ShapeFactory.ParseShape(shapeData , null);
         //  return null;
        }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (_disposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException("ShpParser");
            if (!_opened) throw new InvalidOperationException("ShpParser not open.");

            return this.Current;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<Shape> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator<Shape>)this;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (System.Collections.IEnumerator)this;
    }
}
```

}

how you can use the ShpParser

```
using (var shapefile = new ShpParser("my.shp")
{
   foreach (Shape shape in shapefile)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("ShapeType: {0}", shape.Type);
   }
}
```